# Can I use CSS to reverse the display order of two elements?

Tags: css, html

This sounds crazy, but bear with me. I'm writing a page that basically consists of the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="child1">...</div>
    <div is="child2">...</div>
</div>
```

I want the page to appear different depending on whether it's being rendered for the screen or for printing, implemented through the magic of media queries. In particular, when printing, I want `#child2` to appear on the page *before* `#child1`.

Is there any way I can swap their order without resorting to javascript, and preferably without nasty absolute positioning and whatnot?

I should add, "before" in this context means "directly under."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, with flex boxes - http://jsfiddle.net/F8XMk/

```
#container{
  display: flex;    
  flex-flow: column;
}

#child1{
  order: 2;
}

#child2{
  order: 1;    
}
```

Newer browser support for flex is pretty good. You could also hack your way through it with negative margins :)

Answer (score 2):

The following code will sort your issue and according to caniuse.com is compatible with all browsers except for IE7 and below.

Full support on CSS table display [can be found here](http://caniuse.com/css-table)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="child1">1</div>
    <div id="child2">2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#child2 {
    display:table-header-group;   
}
#child1 {
    display:table-footer-group;    
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution when you don't want to use flexbox because of the effect it would have on other sibling elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using flex

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child1">1</div>
  <div id="child2">2</div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row-reverse;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this in pure CSS. CSS focuses on the presentation part, not the structure of the data that is being displayed.

The next best thing that comes to mind is having duplicate content:

```
<div class="child1 even">...</div>
<div class="child2 odd">...</div>
<div class="child1 odd">...</div>
<div class="child2 even">...</div>
```

and hiding the `odd` class in one view, `even`in another.

It's not great, and it may come with SEO side-effects in some situations, I'm not sure.

It's the only way that comes to mind that doesn't involve server-side processing or JavaScript, though.